# Messaging using sockets on a background thread is producing an error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sockets, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to send a message to another device using sockets and streams, using code found here:

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

This works fine, and I can send a message from one device and have another device receive it and read it without problem. With larger messages, which include things such as NSData, it freezes up my UI while the message is sent, and so I want to run it on a background thread. My code looks the same, except with background threading implemented:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.App.SendMessage", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [mutable setObject:@"Test" forKey:@"TestKey"];

    [self.server sendMessage:mutable toService:service];

});

dispatch_release(queue);
```

And the messaging code looks like this:

```
  NSData* rawPacket = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:packet];

  // Write header: lengh of raw packet
  int packetLength = [rawPacket length];
  [outgoingDataBuffer appendBytes:&packetLength length:sizeof(int)];

  // Write body: encoded NSDictionary
  [outgoingDataBuffer appendData:rawPacket];

  // Try to write to stream
  [self writeOutgoingBufferToStream];



- (void)writeOutgoingBufferToStream {
  // Is connection open?
  if ( !readStreamOpen || !writeStreamOpen ) {
    // No, wait until everything is operational before pushing data through
    return;
  }

  // Do we have anything to write?
  if ( [outgoingDataBuffer length] == 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  // Can stream take any data in?
  if ( !CFWriteStreamCanAcceptBytes(writeStream) ) { 
    return;
  }

  // Write as much as we can
  CFIndex writtenBytes = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, [outgoingDataBuffer bytes], [outgoingDataBuffer length]);

  if ( writtenBytes == -1 ) {
    // Error occurred. Close everything up.
    [self close];
    [delegate connectionTerminated:self];
    return;
  }

  NSRange range = {0, writtenBytes};
  [outgoingDataBuffer replaceBytesInRange:range withBytes:NULL length:0];
}
```

It crashes with the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteMutableData replaceBytesInRange:withBytes:length:]: range {0, 1855} exceeds data length 0'
```

Anybody know why this might be crashing on a background thread?

Comment: Are you accessing `outgoingDataBuffer` from different threads at the same time? That could cause an issue...

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be running the sending code on more than 1 thread - it's only called from one thread?

Comment: @Andew have you found any solution for this issue, because the same issue i am facing.